# Separar las palabras de una frase, eliminando separadores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando un simple programa, el cual tiene como finalidad separar las palabras de un input realizado por el usuario (usando como parámetro una lista de carácteres), eliminar dichos separadores, y finalmente ordenar alfabeticamente la lista.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import re
SEPARATORS = [',',';','.',' ', '']

virginUserInput = input('Ingrese un conjunto de palabras: ')
wordsList = re.split(r"[{}]".format(''.join(SEPARATORS)), virginUserInput)
print(wordsList)

for words in wordsList:
    for character in words:
        if character in SEPARATORS:
            wordsList.remove(character)
    
wordsList.sort()
print(wordsList)
```

Estas son tres pruebas con su resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, el código para separar las palabras utilizando expresiones regulares funciona a la perfección. Ordenar la lista alfabeticamente también funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, no se elimina de la lista los elementos especificados en la lista 'SEPARATORS'.

**EDIT, otra posible solución:**

```
for words in wordsList:
    if words not in SEPARATORS:
        finalList.append(words)
```

La única diferencia es que, en vez de eliminar un elemento de la lista, se agregan los elementos válidos en una lista diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es aconsejable que modifiques la lista que estás iterando, ya que puede dar lugar a resultados inesperados.
Si lo que quieres es eliminar los separadores (aunque con el split te dará espacios en blanco), te recomiendo una *comprenhension list*:

```py
noseplist = [word for word in wordList if word not in SEPARATORS] 
noseplist.sort()
```

**Tu código no funciona debido al bucle anidado que tienes:**

```py
for words in wordsList:
    for character in words:
        if character in SEPARATORS:
            wordsList.remove(character)
```

Estás recorriendo la lista palabra por palabra y acto seguido recorres los caracteres que conforman dicha palabra, al no encontrarse los caracteres que recorres (p,r,o,b,a,n,d,o) no se cumple la condición, por lo tanto no se elimina esa palabra de la lista. 
En el caso de que se encontara más de un carácter que estuviera en SEPARATORS, te saltaría una excepción al intentar eliminar múltiples veces el elemento de la lista (en caso de que no estuviera repetido).

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Sólo tienes que arreglar la expresión regular. La simplifique para que se vea más claro cual es en definitiva:

```
import re

SEPARATORS = '[,;\. ]+'
#virginUserInput = input('Ingrese un conjunto de palabras: ')
virginUserInput = "la, mona jacinta   se ha; puesto una.cinta"
wordsList = re.split(SEPARATORS, virginUserInput)
wordsList.sort()
print(wordsList)
```

Ese '+' al final de los separadores es lo que impide que `wordsList` contenga string vacíos.

produce:

```
['cinta', 'ha', 'jacinta', 'la', 'mona', 'puesto', 'se', 'una']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la idea era abordar este problema sin modificar SEPARATORS. Sin embargo me lo anoto para un futuro.

Comment: @JuanPabloFrersCampos. La expresión regular es la misma; sólo la escribe más corta.  Ojo con el '+' en '[separadores]+'.